# Syste.Web.Ui.Page is 'undefined' after convert from web site to web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to convert my web site project to a web application. After the conversion, every page has the same error on `Inherits System.Web.UI.Page`, also on `Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl` and probably others.
I have created a new test web application and it has exactly the same code without error (when creating a new page). I have checked the References and `System.Web` is definitely there. I followed the instructions in this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx).

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please let me know what error you are getting? Which is present in your question title?

Comment: The error message is "BC30002 Type 'System.Web.UI.Page' is not defined"

Comment: Can you please check whether all the namespaces are correct?